# Not getting Proper rank for Rank() Partition By DateTime

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get the `RANK` by using the below query. I
Don't know exactly where I struck up.
Could anyone help me with this ?

```
SELECT  ID,CMNo,PLat,PLon,RDTime
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CMNo,PLat,PLon,RDTime ORDER BY RDTime) Ranks
FROM    tblMAEH WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE   CMNo = 69
AND     RDTime BETWEEN '2014-10-19 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-10-20 23:59:59.997'
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #test (id     INT,CMNo   INT,PLat   NUMERIC(22, 6),Plon   NUMERIC(22,     6),RDTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #test VALUES      (8630,69,19.08491,72.83919,'21 oct 2014 14:38:13')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES      (8631,69,19.08491,72.83919,'22 oct 2014 18:38:13')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES      (8632,69,19.08491,72.83919,'20 oct 2014 14:39:13')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES      (8633,69,19.08491,72.83919,'20 oct 2014 14:38:13')


SELECT ID,CMNo,PLat,PLon,RDTime,Rank()OVER (PARTITION BY CMNo, PLat, PLon, RDTime Order                            BY RDTime) Ranks
FROM   #test WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE  CMNo = 69
AND RDTime BETWEEN '2014-10-19 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-10-25 23:59:59.997' 

drop table #test
```

[image]

Comment: Add the data of tblMAEH table.

Comment: Actually what is the problem in the output. What output u need?

Comment: Even with your examples, there's not a lot here for me to try to fathom out what you're trying to achieve. Could you try editing the question and telling us what you're trying to do, and what the *expected* output is please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : just need to find out the ranks based on 3,4,5 columns

Answer (score 0):

Due to millisecond part of the datetime the rank didn't get 1 for all the selected row that are marked with the red mark.

i.e for ex.for ID 8630 the RDTime value is 20 Oct 2014 14:38:13

might the actual value of the RDTime Field is 20 Oct 2014 14:38:13.000
and for next row the millisecond part is diffrent. So the rank doesn't get same for all the four rows.

So please eliminate the millisecond part of the RDTime field and then try to requery the same SQL.

Comment: did as you suggested, facing same issue

Comment: please see in my question. added the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I dono how you got that output. I ran the same query in your question but i didnt get that output. Unless u use `row_number()` u wont get that output.  Check this.

```
CREATE TABLE test
  (id     INT,CMNo   INT,PLat   NUMERIC(22, 6),Plon   NUMERIC(22, 6),RDTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES      (8630,69,19.08491,72.83919,'20 oct 2014 14:38:13'),
            (8631,69,19.08491,72.83919,'20 oct 2014 14:39:13'),
            (8632,69,19.08491,72.83919,'21 oct 2014 14:38:13'),
            (8633,69,19.08491,72.83919,'22 oct 2014 14:38:13')

SELECT ID,CMNo,PLat,PLon,RDTime,
       Rank()OVER (PARTITION BY CMNo, PLat, PLon
           ORDER BY RDTime) Ranks
FROM   #test
WHERE  CMNo = 69 

ID      CMNo    PLat        PLon        RDTime                  Ranks
----    ----    ---------   ---------   ----------------------- ----- 
8630    69      19.084910   72.839190   2014-10-20 14:38:13.000 1
8631    69      19.084910   72.839190   2014-10-20 14:39:13.000 2
8632    69      19.084910   72.839190   2014-10-21 14:38:13.000 3
8633    69      19.084910   72.839190   2014-10-22 14:38:13.000 4
```

Comment: in your above query, when i change the date, even tough the rank remains 1 for all the records

Comment: Then show valid examples!!. Show the example with different dates then vl help you..

Comment: please see in my question. added the screen shot

Comment: @user1990383 whats wrong in the output u got according to the query it is correct.

Comment: can you please check the dates, dates are not identical

Comment: Yes dates are not identical but still u will get rank as 1 because you are partitioning by  CMNo, PLat, PLon, RDTime. Check my answer i think that is what u are trying.